# DCGAN understanding generator update step

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

Here is some [DCGAN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06434.pdf) example in Pytorch:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html#training

I wonder why we don't zero discriminator gradients before we update generator? (I added line in original code `# netD.zero_grad() # Q: why we don't do this?`)
Is it because gradients accumulate in some separate variable and don't affect gradients calculation in generator and only can affect update of weights, but on generator update step we only update generator weights so it's fine?

Here is code section from training loop:

```
############################
# (1) Update D network: maximize log(D(x)) + log(1 - D(G(z)))
###########################
## Train with all-real batch
netD.zero_grad()
# Format batch
real_cpu = data[0].to(device)
b_size = real_cpu.size(0)
label = torch.full((b_size,), real_label, dtype=torch.float, device=device)
# Forward pass real batch through D
output = netD(real_cpu).view(-1)
# Calculate loss on all-real batch
errD_real = criterion(output, label)
# Calculate gradients for D in backward pass
errD_real.backward()
D_x = output.mean().item()

## Train with all-fake batch
# Generate batch of latent vectors
noise = torch.randn(b_size, nz, 1, 1, device=device)
# Generate fake image batch with G
fake = netG(noise)
label.fill_(fake_label)
# Classify all fake batch with D
output = netD(fake.detach()).view(-1)
# Calculate D's loss on the all-fake batch
errD_fake = criterion(output, label)
# Calculate the gradients for this batch, accumulated (summed) with previous gradients
errD_fake.backward()
D_G_z1 = output.mean().item()
# Compute error of D as sum over the fake and the real batches
errD = errD_real + errD_fake
# Update D
optimizerD.step()

############################
# (2) Update G network: maximize log(D(G(z)))
###########################
netG.zero_grad()
# netD.zero_grad() # Q: why we don't do this?
label.fill_(real_label)  # fake labels are real for generator cost
# Since we just updated D, perform another forward pass of all-fake batch through D
output = netD(fake).view(-1)
# Calculate G's loss based on this output
errG = criterion(output, label)
# Calculate gradients for G
errG.backward()
D_G_z2 = output.mean().item()
# Update G
optimizerG.step()
```

Answer (score 3):

> .. gradients accumulate in some separate variable ..

Yes. That is correct. They are two storages (read "variables") - one for parameters and another for its *gradients*.

> .. don't affect gradients calculation in generator ..

Also correct. Let's look at the computation graph for the relevant part

```
(x) -----> netG ----> (fake) -> netD -> (output)
             ^                   ^
(G_params) --|                   |
                                 |
                (D_params) ------|
```

Here, things inside `()` are tensors and rest are "pure computation units". I have explicitly depicted the parameters as *inputs* to their own computation units. When you hit `.backward()`, the following computations take place (read backwards)

```
(GRAD_x) <----- netG <---- (GRAD_fake) <- netD <- (GRAD_output)
                  |                         ^
(GRAD_G_params)<--|                         |
                                            |
                       (D_params) ----------|
```

I have replaced each variable with their gradients (i.e. `GRAD_*`) in the backward pass.

You see, there is no `GRAD_D_params` because its just not *required* to go further into `netG` since `netG` has *no role* in producing `D_params` (they are standalone entities associated only with `netD`).

Simply stated, just because the flow is "going through" `netD` does not mean it is required to compute/use gradient w.r.t its parameters. Computation of `GRAD_fake` does not require `GRAD_D_params` (however it requires `D_params`), which is why there is no reason to clear up the old `GRAD_D_params`. But technically, there is no harm either in clearing up `GRAD_D_params`.

---

Question in comment: How `GRAD_fake` is obtained with `GRAD_output` and `D_params` ?

Its simple chain rule. Let's rename the variable

```
fake -> x
netD -> f()
output -> y
D_params -> p
GRAD_output -> del_L/del_y
```

Then the forward computation simplifies to `y = f(x, p)`. It doesn't matter what the form of `f()` is, computing gradient of `x` w.r.t some loss `L`

[image]

would require two things, 1. [image], which is basically `GRAD_output`; 2. [image] or equivalently [image], which is basically a complicated function involving `(x, p)` (not their derivatives).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how `GRAD_fake` is obtained using only `GRAD_output` and `D_params` ?

Comment: See the edit at the end. @mrgloom

Answer (score 2):

The generator and discriminator are defined as separate models and each one stores its gradients

In the example you link they have already done the `backwards` for the discriminator loss.  For the next step you mention `(2) Update G network` they only care about the Generator loss so they only reset the `Generator` gradient to update based on the calculations made on the step.

When the loop finishes and starts again in step `(1) Update D network` they reset the discriminator gradients again to be able to backpropagate based on step 1 operations

I'm assuming they don't do reset `D` gradients since there is no need for them on step `(2)`, they dont care about the values. Is only at step `(1)` they will reset to compute loss over the calculations made.

Comment: On `errG.backward()` we go through `netD` first, so the question is why the gradients stored in `netD` before do not affect the `netG` gradients calculation?